# iOS add beep to barcode scanner

Tags: ios, objective-c, barcode, beep

I have been using the Scanning Barcodes with iOS 7 (Objective-C) from infragistics and it works well.  I am trying to add a beep when it completes a successful scan but keep getting an error.  I'm sure its an easy fix for someone who knows more than I.

```
-(void)loadBeepSound{
    // Get the path to the beep.mp3 file and convert it to a NSURL object.
    NSString *beepFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/beep.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *beepURL = [NSURL URLWithString:beepFilePath];

    NSError *error;

    // Initialize the audio player object using the NSURL object previously set.
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:beepURL error:&error];
    if (error) {
        // If the audio player cannot be initialized then log a message.
        NSLog(@"Could not play beep file.");
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSLog(@"beepFilePath %@", beepFilePath);
    }
    else{
        // If the audio player was successfully initialized then load it in memory.
        [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
}
```

The Error is logging as -

```
-Could not play beep file.
-The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10875.)
-beepFilePath /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/22BB6164-82F8-46E5-B4B6-  4C91BCA2B7E9/ReThink Edu App.app/beep.mp3
```

and so it seems to be an issue with loading the beep sound but it is in the main bundle and the target membership box is ticked.  Maybe I'm just trying to go about this the wrong way!

Comment: could you log out beepFilePath with the error and update the question, thanks.

Comment: i guess i don't know what you're asking

Comment: I want to see that it is getting back a valid file path, that would be the most obvious point of failure.

Comment: Instead of this: NSURL *beepURL = [NSURL URLWithString:beepFilePath]; Try this instead: NSURL *beepURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:beepFilePath];

Comment: That fixed it Mike! How can I give you credit?

Comment: Glad it worked! I posted my answer, can you accept it? Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
    NSURL *beepURL = [NSURL URLWithString:beepFilePath];
```

Try this instead:

```
    NSURL *beepURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:beepFilePath];
```

Comment: Even easier is to replace all of the path/URL code with: `NSURL *beepURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"beep" withExtension:@"mp3"];`

Comment: Yes, that is even better.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `[NSURL URLWithString:beepFilePath];` it only gets string of the folder path like `Users/***/folder/etc`.

So use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:beepFilePath];` this code to will full path like `file:///Users/***/folder/etc`.

**Working Code:**

```
NSURL *beepURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:beepFilePath];
```

**Optional Method:**

```
NSURL *beepURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:///%@", beepFilePath]];
```